# How to send table data from HTML form submit via ajax call to Spring MVC controller

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, jsp, html-table, form-data

Say i have a HTML table in a format similar to this

```
<form> <table id="a">
    <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Series</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="b">
    <tr><td>Enhancer</td><td>Enhancement</td><td>50</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Plans</td><td>Plan</td><td>50</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" action="SomeControllerAction" /></form>
```

which has two rows under the headings "Name","Series" and "Value" .

I need to send this data via a **form** submit to a **Spring Controller** with **Ajax** where i can get or set the values for each row iteratively in a Model. 
I am not sure how to achieve this . That is how to send the data in a table to a spring controller method and get the values .

Help with code segments! 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the previous answer is correct, I would suggest to introduce a class that contains three fields : `name`, `series` and `value`.
This class should have a meaningful name.
Here I named it `MyObject` because I don't know what you app is about.

**MyObject** :

```java
public class MyObject {

    private String name, series;
    private Integer value;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

**Controller** (the return type might be different)

```java
@PostMapping("/series")
@ResponseBody
public List<MyObject> postSeries(@RequestBody List<MyObject> myObjects) {
    myObjects.forEach(System.out::println);
    // Handle myObjects
    return myObjects;
}
```

**JSP**

```jsp
<table id="tableMyObjects">
    <thead id="a">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Series</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="b">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="name"  /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="series" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="value" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="series" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="value" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="postButton">Post myObjects</button>
```

**jQuery**

```jquery
$('#postButton').click(function() {
    var myObjects = [];
    $('#b tr').each(function(index, item) {
        var $item = $(item);
        myObjects.push({
            name: $item.find("td input[name='name']").val(),
            series: $item.find("td input[name='series']").val(),
            value: $item.find("td input[name='value']").val(),
        });
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: '/series',
        method: 'POST',
        contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(myObjects)
    })
    .done(function(myObjects) {
        // handle success
    })
    .fail(function() {
        // handle fail
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript/jquery you can do that easily.

Generate a input type hidden text field while iterating the table content like below with the same name.

```
<tbody id="b">
    <tr>
      <td>
       <input type="hidden" name="Name" value="Enhancer" />
       Enhancer
      </td>
      <td>
       <input type="hidden" name="Series" value="Enhancement" />
       Enhancement
      </td>
      <td>
       <input type="hidden" name="Value" value="50" />
       50
     </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

and then get all the hidden fields values by name like below.

```
$("[name='Name']").val();
$("[name='Series']").val();
$("[name='Value']").val();
```

and then in controller accept those parameters as an array like below.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
       public String create(@RequestParam(value = "Name") String[] Name,
               @RequestParam(value = "Series") String[] Series,
               @RequestParam(value = "Value") String[] Value,
               BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest){
             //code goes here
}
```

**NOTE : You have to write javascript code to set the hidden field values for multiple rows something like this [Call javascript function with if JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925219/call-javascript-function-with-if-jstl)**

Comment: looks good , but how do i set table data in a Model (with getters and setter) for each row . say using modelattribute ?